# Diferença entre “sobre”, “em cima”, “acima” e “em”, e entre “sob”, “em baixo” , “abaixo” e “debaixo”?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças, preposições

*Primum scriptum*: pesquisei pela diferença via Google, mas apenas apresentava sobre se é “em cima” ou “*encima”.

Tanto as palavras “sobre”, “em cima”, “acima” e “em” quantos as palavras “sob”, “em baixo” (“embaixo” no português brasileiro), “abaixo” e “debaixo” são usadas para se referir a partes ou inferiores ou superiores, mas qual é a diferença entre usar, por exemplo, “o livro está sobre a cama” e “o livro está em cima da cama”?

Ou seja:

Qual a diferença entre usar “sobre”, “em cima”, “acima” e “em”? E

qual a diferença entre usar “sob”, “em baixo”, “abaixo” e “debaixo”?

Comment: Temos duas perguntas .  Porque não dividi-la em duas questões?

Comment: @Centaurus, pensei nisso, mas creia que se a diferença entre as para partes superiores ou inferiores fosse respondida, as da outra seriam apenas o inverso.

Comment: What about "debaixo"?

Comment: @Centaurus, vou adicionar.

Comment: No meu livro, "embaixo" como advérbio é uma palavra só.

Comment: @Centaurus, no português brasileiro, é “embaixo”; no português português, é uma locução, “em baixo”. Fonte: Priberam (pesquisando “em baixo”).

Comment: O "em" não deveria estar na colocação sobre, em cima, acima...

Comment: @Lambie, por que dizes isso?

Comment: Sabe o que é uma colocação?

Comment: @Lambie, apenas sei no sentido literal.

Comment: Na língüística, colocação é a probabilidade de palavras estarem no mesmo contexto ou se encontrarem em contextos ligados. Nesse caso, o "em" estaria com: nele(s), nela(s), dele(s), dela(s), etc. por exemplo. sobre/debaixo da cama. Não existe: em cama.

Comment: @Lambie, estás dizendo que "em" tem vários significados, então, não se aplica aqui. Entendi certo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta resposta baseia-se na minha experiência de falante de português europeu. Poderá haver algumas diferenças subtis relativamente ao Brasil. Vou também focar sobretudo os sentidos espaciais.

### *Sobre* e *em cima de*

São sinónimos quando há contacto:

> Deixei-te a roupa lavada **em cima da** cama
> Deixei-te a roupa lavada **sobre** a cama

Mas *sobre* é formal: neste exemplo, em Portugal, toda a gente usaria *em cima de*. Mas se não há contacto, usamos *sobre*:

> Pairavam nuvens **sobre** a cidade

Encontro esta diferença refletida nas definições do Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001). Notem o “na parte superior de”, que implica contacto, na definição de *em cima de*; e o “maior ou menor afastamento” na definição de *sobre*:

> **cima** […] **em cima de**. *loc[ução] prep[osicional]* 1. Sobre; na parte superior de. *Deixou as cartas em cima da secretária* […]

> **sobre** […] **1.** Localização no espaço superior a um ponto de referência, com maior ou menor afastamento em relação ao mesmo. ≈ em cima de.

### *Acima de*

Cito o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), o mais completo que encontrei para esta locução:

> **acima¹** […] **acima de**. *loc[ução] prep[osicional]*  1. Para um lugar ou parte situada em plano ou nível superior a. ≠ abaixo de. *«levou a mão espalmada acima dos olhos»* […] 2. Num lugar ou parte situada em plano ou nível superior a.  ≠ abaixo de. *Ela vive dois andares [’pisos’] acima de nós. *«No quadro eléctrico, acima da portinha que dava acesso à carlinga, acendera-se o já o disco premonitório: ‘Use o cinto’.»* […] 3. Num lugar ou parte situada mais a norte de. *A Ericeira fica acima de Colares*. 4. De idade superior a; mais velho do que. ≠ abaixo de. *Só podem entrar pessoas acima dos 21 anos* 5. Em ou com categoria superior a.  ≠ abaixo de. *Quem está acima de ti na empresa?* […] 6. Em posição qualitativa superior a. ≠ abaixo de. *A inteligência do seu filho está acima da média* […] 7. Em quantia ou quantidade superior a. ≠ abaixo de. Só se aceitam cheques acima dos cinco contos. *«as pensões aumentaram sempre acima da inflação.»* […]

Nos vários pontos,  *acima de* compara duas posições como se estivessem ambas numa escala, e a diferença pudesse ser medida: pisos num edifício, anos de idade, categorias numa hierarquia, etc. A indicação de distâncias leva normalmente a preferir *acima de: as nuvem pairavam uns mil metros acima da cidade*. Nalguns casos *sobre* e *acima de* são praticamente sinónimos:

> Suspenso do teto, **sobre** a mesa, brilhava um candeeiro
> Suspenso do teto, **acima da mesa**, brilhava um candeeiro

*Acima de* dá talvez uma ideia de maior distância.

### *Sob, debaixo de* e *embaixo de*

Comparando as definições do Aulete, [*debaixo de*](https://www.aulete.com.br/debaixo) e [*embaixo de*](https://www.aulete.com.br/embaixo) parecem-me sinónimos: “morava debaixo do viaduto”, “a bicicleta está embaixo da escada”. Tenho de me ficar pelo “parece-me”, porque em Portugal usa-se *debaixo de*, mas não *embaixo de*.

Basicamente, nos sentidos espaciais, *sob* é o oposto de *sobre* e *debaixo de* (e espero que *embaixo de*) é o oposto de *em cima de*. Uma diferençazinha, é que *em cima de* implica contacto, mas *debaixo de* não: os sapatos debaixo da cama estão assentes no chão, não estão colados à face inferior da cama.

### *Abaixo de*

*Abaixo de* é o oposto de *acima de*. Cito novamente o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa

> **abaixo¹** […] **abaixo de**.  *loc[ução] prep[osicional]* 1. Num lugar ou parte situada em plano ou nível superior a.  ≠ acima de. *Ela vive dois andares [’pisos’] abaixo de nós. *«algumas polegadas abaixo do alvo a que atirava»* […] 3. De idade inferior a; mais novo do que. ≠ acima de. *Abaixo de mim só há um rapaz* 3. Em categoria hierárquica inferior a. ≠ acima de. *Ele está logo abaixo do director* […] 4. Em posição qualitativa inferior a.  ≠ acima de. *A inteligência dele está muito abaixo da tua* 5. Em quantia ou quantidade superior a. ≠ acima de. *«O desemprego está, e continua a estar, mais de 3% abaixo da média europeia» […]

Faltam aqui as definições exemplos correspondentes a os pontos 1 e 3 de *acima de*,
mas parece-me que foi esquecimento: nós podemos dizer *levou a mão abaixo do umbigo* (“acima dos olhos” no ponto 1 de *acima de*) e *Colares fica abaixo [sul] da Ericeira* (ponto 3 de *acima de*).

### *Em*

***Em*** substitui *sobre, em cima de* e também *dentro de* quando indica a posição normal e esperada. Comparem:

> O gato deitou-se **no** sofá (em cima do sofá)
> O gato deitou-se **debaixo do** sofá
>
> O vinho está **em cima do** frigorífico (’geladeira’ no Brasil)
> O vinho está **no** frigorífico (dentro do frigorífico)
>
> Deitou-se **na** cama (presumivelmente debaixo dum lençol e talvez um cobertor)
> Deitou-se **em cima da** cama (definitivamente sem nada por cima)
> Deitou-se **debaixo da** cama

E naturalmente pomos o chapéu na cabeça, não em cima da cabeça. ***Em*** pode ainda indicar **várias outras posições**: *mosca no teto, quadro na parede, anéis nos dedos, brinco na orelha, flor no cabelo, brilhozinho nos olhos*, etc. Em cada um destes casos, *em* indica a posição normal e esperada, mas nós não temos outra preposição ou locução preposicional para descrever essa posição de forma mais precisa. E consigo pensar num único exemplo em que *em* pode ser substituído por *debaixo de*: *ninho de andorinha no beiral*.

Comment: Eu não acho que em se substitui a sobre e em cima de.  O gato durmiu na caixa, por exemplo. A ideia de em nada tem a ver intrinsecamente com em cima e debaixo etc.

Comment: @Lambie "O gato dormiu na caixa" - "_Em substitui sobre, em cima de e também **dentro de** quando indica **a posição normal e esperada**._" Parece fazer sentido para mim, nesse caso eu entendo como "o gato dormiu dentro da caixa".

Comment: @RafaelTavares Claro, exato. O gato dormiu dentro da caixa. Por isso, não funciona a colocação de em com as outras palavras!

Answer (score 2):

Realmente essas palavras são bastante confusas pelos sinônimos utilizados em frases parecidas. Mas também há uma ou outra diferença.

"SOBRE" e 'EM CIMA DE" são exatamente a mesma coisa quando se refere a algo como "as roupas estão sobre/em cima da cama". Porém, SOBRE também significa falar/escrever algo, como "este livro é SOBRE receitas."

"ACIMA" não é a mesma coisa que "EM CIMA DE". "ACIMA" é algo mais superior ou mais alto. "O supervisor está ACIMA da atendente" significa que ele tem um 'poder' maior de decisão. Já em "aqueles livros estão ACIMA daquelas roupas"- que já estão em cima da cama - significa que eles estão em um lugar ainda mais alto que as roupas. Se for apenas uma coisa, não se deve usar "ACIMA" como "os livros estão acima da cama", é mais uma questão de concordância e deixar a frase mais "limpa e formal"
"EM" refere-se a lugar, mas não como "em cima de algo". EM pode ser somada com A ou O, transfornando a palavra em "NA" e "NO". É uma palavra usada como "ela está EM casa", ou "ele está NO (em + o) trabalho.

Agora vamos para as outras palavras relacionadas;

SOB e EMBAIXO são exatamente os antônimos de SOBRE e EM CIMA: "A mala está SOBRE a cama' refere-se que está em cima da mesma. "A mala está SOB a cama" significa que está embaixo dela.

Já "ABAIXO" seria o contrário se "ACIMA": "aquele estagiário está abaixo do novo contratado". Porém, também significa que algo/objeto está em um nível mais baixo que outro e, por concordância, fica melhor utilizar o termo "EMBAIXO".

DEBAIXO é também sinônimo de EMBAIXO: "a toalha está DEBAIXO" das roupas. Porém, DEBAIXO, a meu ver é uma palavra mais comum/social e EMBAIXO eu já considero mais formal. Depende muito do contexto da frase.

ACIMA e ABAIXO também podem referir-se a valores: "o valor do arroz está ACIMA do normal."

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Julia, obrigado pela tua contribuição, mas neste site tentam-se usar referências nas respostas. Obrigado pela resposta de qualquer jeito.

Comment: Achei que fosse uma resposta ótima e que nestes casos a melhor referência é um falante nativo de alto nível.

Answer (score 1):

- "em cima de algo" - on top of something
- "em baixo de algo" - under (and covered by) something
- "acima de algo" - over and above something, but more as a direction than an actual place, away from in the upward direction,
- "abaixo de algo" - under, beneath, as a direction than an actual place, away from in the downward direction
- "sobre" - above, about, especially metaphorically about
- "sob" - under, especially if metaphorical rather than actually a location (e.g., "sob controle" - "under control")

  - "sob" is not used much in common vernacular in Brazil, some natives mistake it with "sobre"
- "em" - generic "in" or "at" preposition
- "dentro" - inside

So, "the book is on the table" (haha) - "o livro esta em cima da mesa." Não "sobre a mesa" that sounds like the book was hovering over the table.

Comment: Gunther, obrigado pela resposta, mas por que ela está em inglês? Por sinal, neste site, tenta-se usar referências para fortalecer as palavras da resposta; não é uma obrigação, mas perde-se muita força em relação a se houvesse uma referência. Porém, obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Gunther, "sobre a mesa" means exactly on the table.  "Numa casa portuguesa fica bem, pão e vinho sobre a mesa".   In this case, bread and wine are not flying over the table.